# Imported dae from SketchUp

Tags: mesh, remesh, dae

I import a dae file from sketchup into Blender and go to edit mode.
The pic is the mesh generated by the dae file. How do I remove the lines going from the circle to the edges? My aim is to have a clean mesh so I can subdivide and add some texture.
[image]

Not the result I was looking for.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>X</kbd> and choose *Limited Dissolve*, this will get rid of most of the edges. But note: the hole in the middle needs at least one connection to the outside, so you will never get rid of all edges.

If you want to have more control, let's say each outer corner should have one connection edge to the hole in the middle, just select all edges you don't want to keep, then again press <kbd>X</kbd> and choose *Dissolve Edges*.